# Desktop sharing failing between 12.04 and 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, remote-desktop

On both machines I have

- Desktop Sharing and
- Remote Desktop Viewer (vinagre)

up and running.  On both machines in Desktop Sharing Preferences I have enabled

- Allow other users to view your desktop and
- Allow other users to control your desktop

But almost nothing is working.  The only thing that is working is that from the 14.04 machine's Remote Desktop Viewer I can see both of the machines on the network.  Selecting the 12.04 machine results in a brief hang and then a "Connection closed" message.  From the 12.04 machine I can't see any machines on the network from Remote Desktop Viewer so I can't even try to connect.

Any ideas how to start debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since moved on to a slightly different set up, but I believe I found the source of my problem, which turns out to be quite simple:  The firewall on my host machine was set up to block almost all connections.

On the host machine I could see that the firewall was active by typing

```
sudo ufw status
```

To allow the remote desktop connection, I ran

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.[client] to 192.168.1.[host] port 5900
```

Then everything worked as advertised.